# incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix

Tags: r

I have met problems with my assignment which is generate 100 samples with n=100 for exponential distribution. Then, I have to estimate the parameter by using Maximum of Likelihood Estimation (MLE). I have coded the questions as below but I have met an error stated "incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix". Can I know what does this means? Any wy to solve this?

Your response will be greatly appreciated.

```
nsam=10^2
minuslogL=rep(1,nsam)
MaxLikeEst=rep(1,nsam)
for(i in 1:nsam){
  exp=rexp(100,5)
  minuslogL[i]=function(lambda){-sum(dexp(exp,lambda[i],log = TRUE))}
  library(stats4)
  MaxLikeEst[i]=mle(minuslogL[i],start = list(lambda=5))
  summary(MaxLikeEst)
  i=i+1
}
Error in minuslogL[i] <- function(lambda) { : 
  incompatible types (from closure to double) in subassignment type fix
```